# How to reinstall Grub after burg

Tags: grub2, burg

How is burg different from Grub. 
I have installed burg and would like to know if at some point I want to go back to grub, how can I wipe burg and install grub back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restore GRUB, I think you have to type this into the terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Where /dev/sda is your hard drive.

Comment: Does it mean that Grub does not get wiped out after Burg?

Comment: Not automatically, but I personally purge it (with sudo apt-get purge grub) because of I'm happy with burg

Answer (score 3):

Burg Manager is an application to easily install Burg (along with the default Burg themes and a Burg emulator) and change most of the Burg settings such as the timeout, download and install new themes, **remove Burg and restore Grub 2**, set the default operating system and many advanced options.

you can get it from [here](http://buc.billeragroup.net/?page_id=15)

Comment: I tried Burg Manager on Maverick but I get a dependency error. Any idea, how can I easily install it. Is there any ppa for maverick.

Comment: yes i updated my post donwload from there