# boot problem with ubuntu and windows 8

Tags: boot, windows

i have a hp dv6 system. on which i was having the windows 8 installed.
as i was interested in downloading the ubuntu 12.10 along with windows 8(not inside) .i have made separate partition in ubuntu 12.10 but some how it backfires and now i am not able to boot windows 8 and ubuntu.

with windows 8 there is no drive to access the drive partition that has OS.
with ubuntu i am getting blank screen.

i am thinking that i have problem in system partition but i am not able to solve it.
Plz help me. i am  in a venerable condition...

i have tried booting the window with the help of installation cd but iam not succesful in any of the method -

1-reset PC
2-RECOVERY 
3- from command prompt i tried to check disks but it is not showing anything

Comment: Try [reinstalling **GRUB**](http://askubuntu.com/q/9592/62483).

Answer (score 0):

i have recently setup a dual boot system of Xubuntu 12.10 with a pre-installed windows 8 (UEFI). I have faced similar problems just like you. After shrinking the windows 8 partition and installing Xubuntu (in UEFI mode), grub2 offered me Xubuntu and windows 8. However, only Xubuntu was bootable.

I was able so solve this issue by making use of the boot repair tool applying the recommended repair. After that windows 8 was bootable but my grub menu was a little bit messy (a problem easy to fix using grub customizer).

There are many questions relating to dual boot setups, its definitely worth to browse around since many questions have been already answered.

Best
CEW