# Grub boot is changed! HELP!

Tags: grub2

I am new to Ubuntu. First of all I have dual OS in my system *(Windows and Ubuntu)*. I downloaded Grub Customize and It was working fine (Giving me options to select my OS in the boot menu), but when I updated my Ubuntu OS it did something with Grub and now instead of it asking me to select my OS in the boot menu, it gives me a command line like this: `grub>`

what should i do to get to start my OS and how do i change it back to normal! thanks

Comment: Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Ysv.png) ? Try boot-repair from an Ubuntu live disk.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Stuck in GRUB Rescue Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232215/stuck-in-grub-rescue-mode)