# Switched Automatic mount for my only partition with a boot

Tags: boot, command-line, boot-partition

I have linux installed and partitioned on my internal hard drive.  I was working on setting up a boot able usb drive to run Kali linux and I messed up somewhere to where I cant boot.

I don't care about the usb drive anymore but rather I'm stuck in recovery mode.
I know where my boot drive is at but i was ignorant and turned the automatic mount option off right before I tried to boot the secondary linux from the usb drive.

When Ubuntu boots. It says mount point mnt/Generic_usb12342345356324etcetc is not found or doesn't have a boot.  Unless I can get my computers info from the recovery cmd then all I know for sure is....

Dell latitude.... its more then 10 years old but was my fathers whom is the Head of IT department where he works.  SO its still a pretty decent machine

I have some programming background but just super basic and kinda computer smart so you don't have to give me the complete dummy version lol.

I do know that i could just wipe the drive clean and start from scratch but I am trying to learn what I had done wrong.  I post this in search of help and understand you will need more information.

Comment: this may provide some clues... yell out again if you have issues https://askubuntu.com/questions/232215/stuck-in-grub-rescue-mode

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have added a mount configuration for your USB drive in `/etc/fstab` which tries to mount the stick during boot now and fails after 90 seconds or so as the device is not found.

Once you get into the recovery terminal, you should be able to edit `/etc/fstab` (e.g. using the command `nano /etc/fstab` - `sudo` should not be required as the recovery shell is running as root).

Simply locate the line containing `/mnt/Generic_usb12342345356324...` (or whatever your not found mountpoint is) and remove it, or if you are unsure, comment it out by adding a `#` at the beginning of that line.

Then reboot. It should no longer look for that partition if you did everything right.