# error: symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found [upgrade Ubuntu18.04 to 20.04]

Tags: 18.04, grub2, 20.04, grubrescue, grub-efi

I updated the system from 18.04 to 20.04 via the terminal. When the computer restarts, the black screen appears with the above written mention.

What should I do to fix the problem (without obviously losing the files and programs on the disk)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183951/grub-file-filters-not-found-after-ubuntu-19-10-upgrade and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1848797

Answer (score 1):

What DID NOT WORK

1. I had the same issue and above solution by @rapid3642 DID NOT WORK. The CHROOT case was not the right case for me because I could use `F12` and able to log in to linux without issue. I also tried running the above commands as chroot on ubuntu system / partition directly ( without the mounting part as I had ubuntu installed and working )
2. [Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) also did not work although it seems to be the utility which was supposed to be a clean gui.

I used a comment from [Kristina Kovacek](https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/1242/grub-file-filters-not-found-after-ubuntu-19-10-upgrade) to get the idea of what we need to do.

What did work for me is the [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) utility. Funnily enough it **did not work in the default mode** ( the `Recommended Repair` section ) but I had to change following

Advanced Options -> Grub location

1. Change OS to boot by default to the Linux ( yes you can log into windows but you need to keep linux as Master )
2. Untick Spearate /boot /boot/efi partition
3. Place grub into `<your linux partition such /dev/sda>`

I also removed one other option making sure that by default the GRUB looks into windows I dont remember what it was ( even though I executed the procedure just few moments ago

NOTE that **there are instructions that you need to follow** and commands that you need to execute manually which also involves purging the grub-install from the linux partition ( which in retrospect might have sufficed. )

Answer (score 0):

Great question, this actually just happened to me and I got it working, I did find some really useful information online and I am happy to share it with you. Being that you asked this a month ago I am sure you are most likely not in the same situation but if you are here is what worked for me.

Firstly I have my Ubuntu 18LTS running inside a VM on a ESXI server. This is the one that had the same issue. I also want to mention that my brother had Ubuntu 18LTS running on a raspberry pi 4 and was able to complete the update to Ubuntu 20LTS without any issues which was great to see.

I found the solution that worked for me at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot

I was directed to this by finding the help article posted on:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1848797

I did not have anything raided or complicated on my VM so essentially I could skip a lot of the steps, essentially I followed these steps:
Downloaded the same Ubuntu 20 iso from Ubuntu's site (Desktop Image):
https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

Then I attached it to my VM and then forced the VM to boot to bios so that I can set the boot priority for a cd first instead of a HDD.

Then I saved and when it rebooted it allowed me to boot from the iso. I then selected the "Try Ubuntu" selection which gets you into the live Ubuntu version.

Then open a terminal and type in:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

this gave me the needed info for the next step. Then you can mount the HDD you have via:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

for me the command ended up being

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Then I mounted the critical virtual filesystems, run this as a single command:

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

Then Chroot into your normal system:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Reinstall GRUB 2:

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

For me it was:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Recreate the GRUB 2 menu file (grub.cfg):

```
update-grub
```

Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard then reboot by using:

```
sudo reboot
```