# I can't install Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, laptop

I downloaded 22.04 - https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ - (desktop image)

I made a bootable USB drive with Rufus.

I restart the laptop (HP Elitebook 8570w) and this is the error I'm getting when I try to install it.

https://imgur.com/nzf7jiQ

I started The Odin Project (JavaScript course) and it's adapted to Linux instead of Windows 10, so I wanted to make a dual boot. Please give me advice - is my laptop too old, should I try with an older version? Can this be fixed?

Comment: here there is a similar problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183951/grub-file-filters-not-found-after-ubuntu-19-10-upgrade